# how do I declare a variable that doesnt get stored in DB using mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

is there some sort of transient where i get can use a non-field, and still maintaing in the object without storing in the db:

For example:

```
class User
   dont-store :birthday
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use plain old `attr_accessor`.

```
class Customer
  field :name # this is stored
  attr_accessor :credit_card # does not get stored
end
```